# What does this tracert output mean (hovering between two IP addresses)?

Tags: traceroute

I'm sadly spending my morning trying to get Take That tickets for my girlfriend. I did

```
tracert ticketmaster.co.uk
```

and got the following output

```
C:\Users\Alex>tracert ticketmaster.co.uk

Tracing route to ticketmaster.co.uk [209.104.32.143]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  192.168.1.1
  2    26 ms    23 ms    23 ms  89.240.224.1
  3    25 ms    25 ms    31 ms  62.24.254.216
  4    26 ms    27 ms    26 ms  62.24.254.151
  5    25 ms    24 ms    25 ms  xe-11-0-0-rt001.man.as13285.net [78.151.225.3]
  6    44 ms    36 ms    32 ms  xe-11-1-0-rt001.sov.as13285.net [62.24.240.14]
  7    32 ms    31 ms    31 ms  xe-11-2-0-scr001.sov.as13285.net [78.144.1.130]

  8    33 ms    30 ms    32 ms  host-78-144-0-213.as13285.net [78.144.0.213]
  9    33 ms    31 ms    31 ms  ge-0-2-0-0.lonth-inter-2.interoute.net [195.66.2
26.53]
 10    32 ms    34 ms    33 ms  209.104.32.34
 11    33 ms    30 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.33
 12    34 ms    33 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.34
 13    49 ms    41 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.33
 14    38 ms    36 ms    33 ms  209.104.32.34
 15    44 ms    31 ms    32 ms  209.104.32.33
 16    33 ms    33 ms    34 ms  209.104.32.34
 17    32 ms    31 ms    33 ms  209.104.32.33
 18    33 ms    33 ms    30 ms  209.104.32.34
 19    32 ms    30 ms    32 ms  209.104.32.33
 20    34 ms    33 ms    34 ms  209.104.32.34
 21    32 ms    30 ms    32 ms  209.104.32.33
 22    33 ms    43 ms    34 ms  209.104.32.34
 23    86 ms    42 ms    99 ms  209.104.32.33
 24    35 ms    31 ms    30 ms  209.104.32.34
 25    59 ms    31 ms    32 ms  209.104.32.33
 26    32 ms    32 ms    33 ms  209.104.32.34
 27    34 ms    32 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.33
 28    41 ms    32 ms    33 ms  209.104.32.34
 29    33 ms    31 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.33
 30    32 ms    32 ms    31 ms  209.104.32.34

Trace complete.
```

What does/could the hovering between those two IPs mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that the routing table on one of the routers in the loop is screwed up. Try a WHOIS on the addresses and talking to their technical contact; they may not know that it's broken.

Comment: +1 nice routing loop. also possible with more hops in the loop

Answer (score 1):

It's a routing loop. Those two routers each think that the other router has a route to the destination.

Answer (score 0):

It can mean that the router to which .33 needs to send data is down. 
It sometimes happen with my ISP.

Answer (score 0):

[BBC News](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-11650620) reports that the site has crashed. Good luck

Comment: Well then I guess the technical contact probably knows after all...

Comment: What would be interesting is whether this misconfiguration was done on purpose to keep traffic from killing the site. That may be a bit conspiracy theory though :)